# img won't display

Tags: html, css, anchor, image

So I'm very confused and never seen something like this happen before. I have a simple link displaying an img in html. When I load my page, the img does not display. There is no CSS applied to the link or the img. Here's my code, I just need somewhere to start because I have no clue what the problem is.

```
<li>
    <a class="dropDownGif" id="dropDownGifLink" href="#"><img src="../../images/darr.png" /></a>
</li>
```

EDIT:
When pulled up in chrome inspector the link shows the style as display:none; however this is written nowhere in my code, when I put css in to make sure it displays, it still automatically changes to display:none;. And the img path is correct, not sure how to change it to an absolute path though..
Thanks for all the help! hope this extra info helps.

Comment: What do you see in Firebug / Developer Console?

Comment: With the limited information you have given, I suggest you replacing the image path to an absolute path. From which, we can conclude path whether path has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: There must be image path issue, check it with firebug and if the image is on server give us image url to look into.

Comment: On a total side note, I personally never, ever want to see `../../` ever again.

Comment: @Fresheyeball what would be a better alternative to ../../? just curious.

Comment: absolute paths. If your relative path has to go more than one level deep its a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine must be the path to the image http://jsfiddle.net/YuqVu/

Check the served images and their location with inspect element on Chrome.  You can right-click --> inspect element --> click on resources

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with you code at all unless you apply some style. The problem must be your image path.